# Extracting the Cloudant chat json multiple listed logs using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How to read the multiple listed JSON using pandas, we are connecting the Cloudant database and using the date filter to select the period. below is a code snippet. The expected outcome is to extract the JSON parameters into each column.

```
    # Date filter
        log_from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('202210250000.00', "%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f") # Jan 2022
        log_to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('202210310000.00', "%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f")
         
    #Language
    
    lang = ['EN','AR']
        
        fromDateTime = datetime.datetime(log_from_date.year,log_from_date.month,log_from_date.day,log_from_date.hour,log_from_date.minute,log_from_date.second,log_from_date.microsecond) # time in GMT  Format YYYY, MM , DD , HH,MM, SS
        toDateTime =  datetime.datetime(log_to_date.year,log_to_date.month,log_to_date.day,log_to_date.hour,log_to_date.minute,0,0) #fromDateTime + timedelta(hours=interval)
        output_file =  str(fromDateTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"))+'_' + str(toDateTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")) +'.csv'
        fromDateTime = fromDateTime -datetime.timedelta(hours=4, minutes=0)# time in GMT  Format YYYY, MM , DD , HH,MM, SS
        toDateTime   = toDateTime - datetime.timedelta(hours=4, minutes=0) 

epoch = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
from_datetime = (fromDateTime - epoch).total_seconds()*1000
to_datetime = (toDateTime - epoch).total_seconds()*1000
```

#Database connection

```
for language in lang:
    client = Cloudant(cloudant_db_credential['serviceUsername'], cloudant_db_credential['servicePassword'], url=cloudant_db_credential['serviceURL'])
    client.connect()
    # Create an instance of the database.
    
    db = client[cloudant_db]   # client.create_database(databaseName)
    if db.exists:
        rows = []
        result_collection = Result(db.all_docs, include_docs=True)
        
        query = cld.query.Query(    db, #sort =[{"_id": "asc"}] 
                                    selector= {"$and": [ {"requestTime": {"$gt": from_datetime,"$lte": to_datetime}},{"language": language}]},
                                    fields= ["client_channel","language","_id","workspaceId",'conversationId','conversation_id',"requestTime","conversationResponseTime","request","response" ]
                                )
        for doc in query()['docs']:   # for doc in query(limit=100, skip=100)['docs']:
            row = {}
```

if you print the "doc" you will get the below json, I need to extract the below data into the data frame. please note I am passing the date as a filter to loop and download the chat logs

```
doc
{'language': 'AR',
 '_id': 'feee78d26a0e750a7fad9f80819a435d',
 'workspaceId': '',
 'conversationId': '',
 'requestTime': 1666850951804,
 'conversationResponseTime': 1666850951890,
 'request': {'input': {'text': 'تم تنفيذ الخدمة بشكل مغاير عن المتفق عليه في العقد/الفاتورة'},
  'context': {'Language': 'AR',
   'conversation_id': '20c185f1-1788-4b61-9496-d067459dfcc0',
   'system': {'initialized': True,
    'dialog_stack': [{'dialog_node': 'node_7_1594702137463'}],
    'dialog_turn_counter': 2,
    'dialog_request_counter': 2,
    '_node_output_map': {'Welcome': [0],
     'node_3_1589367319164': {'0': [0]},
     'node_7_1594702137463': {'0': [0]}},
    'last_branch_node': 'node_3_1589367319164'},
   'reask': False,
   'state': '',
   'channel': 'DAD',
   'caseType': '',
   'slotsVariable': None,
   'metadata': {'user_id': '20c185f1-1788-4b61-9496-d067459dfcc0'},
   'log': 'user: \r\nwatson: مرحبا, اسمي "نظام الحماية الذكية". أنا هنا لمساعدتك على أية أسئلة لديك بخصوص حماية المستهلك. يمكنك أن تسألني سؤال متعلق بأحد الموضوعات التالية:\n<wcs:newBubble>  <ol> <li> <a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("لدي مشكلة متعلقة بمنتج قد اشتريته")\'> مشكلة متعلقة بمنتج قد اشتريته.</a></li> <li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("لدي مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة طلبتها/تلقيتها")\'> مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة طلبتها/تلقيتها</a></li>\n<li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("لدي مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة تصليح")\'> مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة تصليح</a></li>\n<li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("لدي مشكلة متعلقة بعربون دفعته ولم استرده")\'> مشكلة متعلقة باسترداد عربون</a></li>\n<li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("تم احتساب مبلغ إضافي لبطاقة الائتمان على الفاتورة")\'> احتساب مبلغ إضافي لبطاقة الائتمان على الفاتورة</a></li>\n<li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("اريد الاستفسار عن شكوى/رسالة حل")\'>متابعة شكوى/رسالة حل</a></li>\n</ol><wcs:newBubble>\n\r\nuser: لدي مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة طلبتها/تلقيتها\r\nwatson: \r\n',
   'action': '',
   'counter': 0,
   'language': 'ar',
   'LRDT': 'LEGAL RIGHTS BLANK PLACEHOLDER',
   'wcs_version': '201804021452_AR_PROD',
   'NID': 125,
   'ui_didYouKnow': {'text': ['    <ul>    <li>  على التاجر أو مقدم الخدمة توفير المنتجات والخدمات بالجودة والكفاءة والخصائص والمواصفات المعلن عنها في جميع القنوات الإعلانية.    </li>    <li>  على المستهلك التأكد من توافق المنتجات والخدمات مع المتطلبات.    </li>    <li>  الاتفاقيات والعقود يجب أن تحتوي على جميع البنود والتفاصيل والمتطلبات المتفق عليها.    </li>    <li>  على المستهلك الإحتفاظ بالعقود والفواتير والمستندات لضمان وحفظ حقوقه.    </li>    <li>  تعمل إدارة حماية المستهلك على حماية حقوق المستهلكين من خلال التأكد من إلتزام الأطراف بالبنود والاتفاقيات المبرمة كما تعمل الإدارة كوسيط بين المستهلك والتاجر لتسوية الشكاوى ودياً وذلك حسب قانون حماية المستهلك رقم (24) لعام 2006 والسياسات والأحكام المعمول بها في إقتصادية دبي.    </li>  <li>  حل شكاوى المستهلكين تتضمن:    </li>  <ul>    <li>      الإصلاح أو الإستبدال أو الإسترداد النقدي وذلك حسب طبيعة الشكوى والمنتج.    </li>    <li>   إعادة تقديم الخدمة أو استرداد قيمة الخدمة في حال عدم القدرة على إعادة تقديمها.    </li>    <li>   التعويضات ليست ضمن اختصاص وصلاحيات إدارة حماية المستهلك في إقتصادية دبي.    </li>  </ul>  </ul>'],
    'title': ['أساسيات حماية المستهلك']},
   'residencyStatus': 1,
   'complaintDetails': 'لدي مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة طلبتها/تلقيتها',
   'complaintSubject': 'Watson Complaint - '},
  'requestTime': 1666850951804,
  'call_times': {'MAIN': 0, 'OFFTOPIC': 0, 'EXTERNAL_DEPARTMENT': 0},
  'workspaceId': 'd6befc05-5677-4943-8266-a3033263b8ca'},
 'response': {'status': 200,
  'statusText': 'OK',
  'headers': {'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
   'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, HEAD, OPTIONS',
   'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, X-Watson-Authorization-Token, X-WDC-PL-OPT-OUT, X-Watson-UserInfo, X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out, X-Watson-Metadata',
   'access-control-max-age': '3600',
   'content-security-policy': "default-src 'none'",
   'x-dns-prefetch-control': 'off',
   'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
   'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains, max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;',
   'x-download-options': 'noopen',
   'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
   'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
   'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   'x-dp-watson-tran-id': 'c3500470-8d65-4ba2-b287-8467f26e847b',
   'x-request-id': 'c3500470-8d65-4ba2-b287-8467f26e847b',
   'x-global-transaction-id': 'c3500470-8d65-4ba2-b287-8467f26e847b',
   'server': 'watson-gateway',
   'x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt': '3',
   'x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency': '64',
   'date': 'Thu, 27 Oct 2022 06:09:11 GMT',
   'content-length': '6258',
   'connection': 'close'},
  'result': {'intents': [{'intent': 'DAD_CR_SERVICE_ISSUE',
     'confidence': 0.7743337631225586}],
   'entities': [{'entity': 'sys-number',
     'location': [51, 54],
     'value': '1000',
     'confidence': 1,
     'metadata': {'numeric_value': 1000},
     'interpretation': {'numeric_value': 1000, 'subtype': 'integer'}}],
   'input': {'text': 'تم تنفيذ الخدمة بشكل مغاير عن المتفق عليه في العقد/الفاتورة'},
   'output': {'generic': [{'response_type': 'text',
      'text': 'ولكن أولا، هل يمكن  أن أعرف إذا كانت لديك فاتورة أو عقد أو أي مستندات داعمة؟  <br><br>    لمزيد من المعلومات رجاء مراجعة قسم <b> {{IMPORTANT_INFO}}</b>.  <wcs:newBubble> يمكنك اختيار <wcs:input>نعم</wcs:input> أو <wcs:input>لا</wcs:input>.'}],
    'text': ['ولكن أولا، هل يمكن  أن أعرف إذا كانت لديك فاتورة أو عقد أو أي مستندات داعمة؟  <br><br>    لمزيد من المعلومات رجاء مراجعة قسم <b> {{IMPORTANT_INFO}}</b>.  <wcs:newBubble> يمكنك اختيار <wcs:input>نعم</wcs:input> أو <wcs:input>لا</wcs:input>.'],
    'nodes_visited': ['node_7_1594702244293', 'node_13_1511117348624'],
    'log_messages': []},
   'context': {'Language': 'AR',
    'conversation_id': '20c185f1-1788-4b61-9496-d067459dfcc0',
    'system': {'initialized': True,
     'dialog_stack': [{'dialog_node': 'node_13_1511117348624'}],
     'dialog_turn_counter': 3,
     'dialog_request_counter': 3,
     '_node_output_map': {'Welcome': [0],
      'node_3_1589367319164': {'0': [0]},
      'node_7_1594702137463': {'0': [0]},
      'node_13_1511117348624': [0, 0]},
     'last_branch_node': 'node_13_1511117348624'},
    'reask': False,
    'state': 'INVOICE',
    'channel': 'DAD',
    'caseType': 'Service Executed differently',
    'slotsVariable': None,
    'metadata': {'user_id': '20c185f1-1788-4b61-9496-d067459dfcc0'},
    'log': 'user: \r\nwatson: مرحبا, اسمي "نظام الحماية الذكية". أنا هنا لمساعدتك على أية أسئلة لديك بخصوص حماية المستهلك. يمكنك أن تسألني سؤال متعلق بأحد الموضوعات التالية:\n<wcs:newBubble>  <ol> <li> <a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("لدي مشكلة متعلقة بمنتج قد اشتريته")\'> مشكلة متعلقة بمنتج قد اشتريته.</a></li> <li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("لدي مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة طلبتها/تلقيتها")\'> مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة طلبتها/تلقيتها</a></li>\n<li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("لدي مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة تصليح")\'> مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة تصليح</a></li>\n<li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("لدي مشكلة متعلقة بعربون دفعته ولم استرده")\'> مشكلة متعلقة باسترداد عربون</a></li>\n<li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("تم احتساب مبلغ إضافي لبطاقة الائتمان على الفاتورة")\'> احتساب مبلغ إضافي لبطاقة الائتمان على الفاتورة</a></li>\n<li><a href="#" target="_self" onClick = \'sendVal ("اريد الاستفسار عن شكوى/رسالة حل")\'>متابعة شكوى/رسالة حل</a></li>\n</ol><wcs:newBubble>\n\r\nuser: لدي مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة طلبتها/تلقيتها\r\nwatson: \r\n',
    'action': '',
    'counter': 0,
    'language': 'ar',
    'LRDT': 'LEGAL RIGHTS BLANK PLACEHOLDER',
    'wcs_version': '201804021452_AR_PROD',
    'NID': 125,
    'ui_didYouKnow': {'text': [' الفاتورة هي المستند المطبوع أو المرسل عن طريق القنوات الإلكترونية وتشمل التالي:  <ul>    <li> صيغة الفاتورة:              </li>    <ul>      <li> أن تكون باللغة العربية بالإضافة الى أي لغة أخرى.      </li>      <li> تفاصيل المنتجات / الخدمات بحيث تشمل الوصف والسعر والكمية بشكل مفصل                 </li>      <li> تحديد المجموع الإجمالي بنهاية الفاتورة مع وضع في الحسبان المبلغ المدفوع والمتبقي.                </li>    </ul>    <li> تفاصيل الفاتورة:              </li>    <ul>      <li> اسم وعنوان الشركة.                </li>      <li> تاريخ الشراء والرقم التسلسلي                 </li>      <li> تفاصيل المستهلك                </li>      <li> البيانات المتفق عليها كتاريخ التسليم والتركيب والتوصيل بالإضافة الى البيانات التي تدعم الاتفاق كالمقاسات والرسومات البيانية التي يتم (طباعتها بشكل منفصل وإدراجها مع الفاتورة الأصلية).                </li>      <li>           بيانات الضمان وتشمل مدة الضمان والأجزاء الشاملة بالضمان. (طباعتها بشكل منفصل وإدراجها مع الفاتورة الأصلية)                </li>    </ul>    <li>      ضريبة القيمة المضافة (إن وجدت):             </li>    <ul>      <li> يجب أن تحتوي الفاتورة على بيانات ضريبة القيمة المضافة كما هو موضح أدناه:                </li>      <ol>        <li> القيمة الأصلية للمنتج (دون احتساب الضريبة) مثال 200 درهم                   </li>        <li>          نسبة الضريبة المحددة والمبلغ. مثال ضريبة القيمة المضافة 5% - المبلغ 10 دراهم                  </li>        <li>           القيمة الإجمالية وتشمل ضريبة القيمة المضافة. مثال 210 درهم.                  </li>      </ol>    </ul>    <li> على المستهلك الإحتفاظ بالفاتورة وذلك لحماية حقوقه.              </li>  </ul>'],
     'title': ['فاتورة']},
    'residencyStatus': 1,
    'complaintDetails': 'لدي مشكلة متعلقة بخدمة طلبتها/تلقيتها',
    'complaintSubject': 'Watson Complaint - '},
   'user_id': '20c185f1-1788-4b61-9496-d067459dfcc0'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
final=pd.DataFrame()
for language in lang:
    client = Cloudant(cloudant_db_credential['serviceUsername'], cloudant_db_credential['servicePassword'], url=cloudant_db_credential['serviceURL'])
    client.connect()
    # Create an instance of the database.
    
    db = client[cloudant_db]   # client.create_database(databaseName)
    if db.exists:
        rows = []
        result_collection = Result(db.all_docs, include_docs=True)
        
        query = cld.query.Query(    db, #sort =[{"_id": "asc"}] 
                                    selector= {"$and": [ {"requestTime": {"$gt": from_datetime,"$lte": to_datetime}},{"language": language}]},
                                    fields= ["client_channel","language","_id","workspaceId",'conversationId','conversation_id',"requestTime","conversationResponseTime","request","response" ]
                                )
        for doc in query()['docs']:   # for doc in query(limit=100, skip=100)['docs']:
            final=pd.concat([final,pd.json_normalize(doc)])
```